# LINQ Query can return the counts of each column of DataTable

Tags: linq

I have a query, I am using a data table and I want to see each variable how many rows have values without null and value(-1) in that particular column. If anyone can help me to use the LINQ query and check the numbers.

Example: I have a table (City, Age, Gender) and i want to show the user that which column has blanks.... I mean in my current dataset city & Age has 200 rows but gender has 170 due to punching error so I through the loop to check each column I want to show the counts.

Here is what I have tried but that is not working. And its Vb.net code.

```
    Dim dtRaw As New DataTable
    daGlobal = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(CMD, MyConnection)
    daGlobal.Fill(dtRaw)
    daGlobal.Fill(dtGlobal)

    For Each column As DataColumn In dtRaw.Columns
          Dim xss As String = column.ColumnName
          Dim MyCounts = (From xss In dtRaw.AsEnumerable()
               Where (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xss)).Count())

    Next
```

Comment: Why are you using `xss` twice? Does this even compile? Hint: Types are your friend - what is the type of `xss` in the LINQ?

Comment: Is this data in a SQL server?